# ~bash: command not found to any command after server restart!

Tags: ubuntu

After server restart, none of the command works. Please help.

```
development@q1:~$ ls
-bash: ls: command not found
development@q1:~$ ECHO $PATH
-bash: ECHO: command not found
development@q1:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
development@q1:~$ sudo apt-get update
-bash: sudo: command not found
development@q1:~$
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing that before you rebooted you modified your `PATH` in `/etc/profile` (or perhaps `~/.bashrc`) to be `/var/lib/ruby/gems/1.8` (incorrectly following some guide to make gem-installed programs work because rubygems is too speshul to follow the rest of the world and just put their binaries somewhere accessable).

Do this in your shell:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
```

Now you have a regular set of programs back, and can proceed to hunt down what you did wrong and set things right.